# Calculate area with FME

Tags: fme-form

I have coordinates in decimal degrees and need to calculate area for polygon objects. I tried to use AreaCalculator and set up criteria to find all these bigger than 100 sqm. But result is not as I expected. Should I convert first from decimal degree to metric?

Comment: use a reprojector on your data before your AreaCalculator to convert to Meters - WORLD-MERCATOR would work - then reproject back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, reproject but use `_AZMEA_` as the coordinate system. It's a dynamic equal area projection designed exactly for this. Then simply reproject back. In future the AreaCalculator will have an option to do this reprojection automatically.